# Save a query as CSV file, but can't get table header field names to write in CSV

Tags: php, mysql

I'm successfully creating a CSV file from a query and saving the file on the server, but I can not get the csv to contain the header fields, per the query column names. I am creating a headers array from the mysql_field_name, but can't get it to write the headers to the csv, it only writes the table data. Any thoughts / examples greatly appreciated.

```
//Create a CSV for 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `car_details`"); 
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records'); 
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result); 
$headers = array(); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
{     
       $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i); 
} 
$csv_filename = "Policy-" .$datetime.".csv";
$fp = fopen($csv_filename, 'w+');


if ($fp && $result) 
{     
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
       {
          fputcsv($fp, array_values($row)); 
       } 
}
```

Comment: Well, you didn't write the $headers array (i.e. unused variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing $headers to the file as the first line.

Comment: Of course - i just need to fputcsv($fp, array_values($headers)); before the while loop that writes the data. Can't see wood for the trees sometimes! Thanks for the guidance, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Would look like:

```
...
if ($fp && $result) 
{
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
    {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row)); 
    }
}
```